# linking src components as https not http

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I currently am able to load my page into HTTP and my style sheets are being loaded in as a HTTP link. But when loading into https:// the styles sheets and images don't load in can it be my .htacces file I'm using linking my style sheet using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}">
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect any request made to your site to use https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

try clear your browser cache/history after apply.